# Databricks Prints Only Around 280 lines of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, databricks, azure-data-lake

I'm running some large jobs in Databricks, which for now, include inventorying the data lake.  I'm trying to print all blob names within a prefix (sub-folder).  There are a lot of files in these sub-folders, and I'm getting about 280 rows of file names printed, but then I see this: `*** WARNING: skipped 494256 bytes of output ***`  Then, I get another 280 rows printed.

I'm guessing there is a control to change this, right.  I certainly hope so.  This is designed to work with BIG data, not ~280 records.  I understand that huge data sets can easily crash a browser, but common, this is basically nothing.

Answer (score 6):

you can check all printed values in your driver’s logs

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After a little more research, I stumbled on something that worked for me.

[image]

Also, this will display the contents of a dataframe,

```
display(df)
```

So, that will generate the view you see directly above.